# Convergence of a series for particular values of x

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a problem proving for which values of $x \in R$ does

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x+n}$$

converges?

Is the convergence uniform on $(-1,1)$?

Doing the root test I arrive to $\alpha = \lim \sup \left| \frac{-1}{(x+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right|$
Can I use something like the result $lim \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ for $p>0$ to say $\alpha <1$ and prove convergence?

Or, Am I in the wrong track?

Comment: How is this defined if $x = -n$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: That is not a power series!
The root test is irrelevant!

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is eventually positive for any choice of $x\notin \Bbb Z^{-}$, and hence you have an alternating sum tending to zero. Hence, it converges for any value $x\notin \Bbb Z^{-}$.

Answer (score 0):

For non-integer $x$, this is an alternating sequence, and $\frac{1}{x+n}>0$ eventually and decreasing to zero, hence it's pointwise convergent.

Let $α_n=\sup_{x\in (-1,1)}\frac{1}{x+n}\to 0$.

Then for any positive integers $m$ and $n$ with $m\geq n$ and $x\in(-1,1)$, using the fact that it is an alternating series of real numbers,

$$∣(−1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{x+n+1}+(−1)^{n+2}\frac{1}{x+n+2}+\cdots +(−1)^{m+1}\frac{1}{x+m}∣ \leq \frac{1}{x+n}\leq α_n$$

The term on the RHS is independent of $x$ and can be made as small as desired. From this, it follows that the series is uniformly Cauchy on $(-1,1)$, and thus uniformly convergent.